# Need to migrate a production database to a new server in oracle

Tags: oracle

We want to migrate a production database to a new server

Existing server: Windows 2008/Oracle Enterprise 11g v11.2.0.2/DB size 350GB

New Server: Windows 2012/Oracle Enterprise 12c v12.2.0

As expdp/impdp take many hours due to huge size, please suggest any alternatives.

Comment: Have you tried the parallel option?  That can sometimes make things run an order of magnitude faster.

Comment: How long does export/import take? How much downtime can you have?

Comment: maybe this question is better suited for dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: What are your  hardware restrictions (cpu, ram,  storage)

Answer (score 0):

You want to migrate operating system as well as Oracle version upgrade too. The best choice is export/import. If the size of a database is large and you don't want to take export/import then another option is following.

1. Take a full cold backup of 11g database at the old server.
2. Install new Oracle 12c version software only on the new server.
3. Create spfile,bdump,cdump directories as well as a parameter file.
4. Restore old backup and upgrade it to Oracle 12c.

These process will take also your time and upgrade issues. As per my recommendation best option is export/import. If your database size is 350 gb then your export dump file will be around 100-120gb only (maybe lesser size). It won't take too much time.

Comment: why is export/import the best option? could you elaborate on this?

Comment: If you are upgrading operating system in new server deployment then the operating system also is upgraded as well as Oracle version. If you have the only 350gb database then export dump size may be less than 100gb. During the direct upgrade or manual upgrade you need to restore an 11g database and after that, you can perform the upgrade to 12c. You need to follow up all steps of upgrade guide.During the upgrade you may be encountering with some bugs then the process will be consuming more time and effort. But if you create a new db in 12c and take import then you can save your time and effort.

Comment: you may encounter bugs when you are importing, too. but all bugs you hit you will hit and repair during the migration tests so they will not affect you in your downtime when doing the migration. Some objects aren't handled very well by export/import (e.g. tables that references rowids) Also the restore is done before the migration so all in all I think an in-place upgrade is usually much faster  than an export/import. But most of the time the export will be much simpler. But all in all it is necessary to know the requirements to decide which method is the best.

Comment: I think you should transfer your reasoning from the comment to the post.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce database downtime, use standby technology.

1. Install Oracle software only 11g and 12c on the new server.
2. Perform a hot backup on the old server.
3. Restore the hot backup to the new server.
4. Configure the standby between the Oracle servers 11
5. Make a test migration from 11 to 12 version.
6. Make a test application on new version DB Oracle 12c
7. Make a hot backup on the old server.
8. Restore the hot backup to the new server.
9. Resync the standby between the Oracle servers 11
10. Make productive migration from 11 to 12 version.